# "Preloading" A Dictionary With Keys in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

This is a fairly simple issue, but one I would like to solve, as it *MAY* help with performance.

I want to find out if Swift has a way to create a Dictionary, specifying *ONLY* keys, and maybe no values, or a single value that is set in each entry.

In other words, I want to create a Dictionary object, and "preload" its keys. Since this is Swift, the values could be 0 or nil (or whatever is a default empty).

The reason for this, is so that I can avoid two loops, where I go through once, filling a Dictionary with keys and empty values, and a second one, where I then set those values (There's a practical reason for wanting this, which is a bit out of the scope of this question).

Here's sort of what I'm thinking:

```
func gimme_a_new_dictionary(_ inKeyArray:[Int]) -> [Int:Int] {
    var ret:[Int:Int] = [:]
    for key in inKeyArray {
        ret[key] = 0
    }

    return ret
}

let test1 = gimme_a_new_dictionary([4,6,1,3,0,1000])
```

But I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to do the same thing (as in "language construct" way -I could probably figure out a faster way to do this in a function).

**UPDATE:** The first solution *ALMOST* works. It works fine in Mac/iOS. However, the Linux version of Swift 3 doesn't seem to have the [uniqueKeysWithValues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init) initializer, which is annoying.

```
func gimme_a_new_dictionary(_ inKeyArray:[Int]) -> [Int:Int] {
    return Dictionary<Int,Int>(uniqueKeysWithValues: inKeyArray.map {($0, 0)})
}

let test1 = gimme_a_new_dictionary([4,6,1,3,0,1000])
```

Comment: The `init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` initializer for `Dictionary` is indeed a Swift 4.0 feature.

Comment: Ah! That's why! Nevermind, then...

Comment: Reading comprehension. I've heard of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Swift 4, you can use the dictionary constructor that takes a sequence and use `map` to create the sequence of tuples from your array of keys:

```
let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: [4,6,1,3,0,1000].map {($0, 0)})
```

Comment: That looks like an answer. I'll throw it into my mixer, and see if it does the trick. It just may be mitigated by the performance of map().

Comment: It may be no faster than your method, since `map` is really just a loop.  I guess it depends on what your goal is.

Comment: Thanks! See my update. It works in Mac, but not in Linux. However, you're right. It may not be faster. That said, I would ASSUME that built-in functions like map() are optimized up the yin-yang.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you could optimize your code in terms of allocation by specifying the minimum capacity during the initialization. However, one liner may be the above answer, it's essentially allocation and looping to add 0 in each position.

```
func gimme_a_new_dictionary(_ inKeyArray:[Int], minCapacity: Int) -> [Int:Int] {
    var ret = Dictionray<Int, Int>(minimumCapacity: minCapacity)
    for key in inKeyArray {
        ret[key] = 0
    }

    return ret
}

let test1 = gimme_a_new_dictionary([4,6,1,3,0,1000])
```

Take a look at this official documentation:

```
    /// Use this initializer to avoid intermediate reallocations when you know
    /// how many key-value pairs you are adding to a dictionary. The actual
    /// capacity of the created dictionary is the smallest power of 2 that
    /// is greater than or equal to `minimumCapacity`.
    ///
    /// - Parameter minimumCapacity: The minimum number of key-value pairs to
    ///   allocate buffer for in the new dictionary.
    public init(minimumCapacity: Int)
```